# How to prevent polluting a rails object when using form_for and .new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I have a model:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :activity_states
end
```

I want to render options for new activity states and render existing activity states.  However when I use this form_for:

```
<%= form_for activity.activity_states.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :state_type, :value => activity_state_type %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :activity_id %>
    <%= f.submit submit_label, :disable_with => 'sending...' %>
<% end %>
```

for creating new temporary activity_state models to use as the basis for new activity_states it pollutes the activity object with `nil` activity states so instead of Activity having the activity states:

```
[#<ActivityState id: 7353, activity_id: 2033, state_type: 0, created_at: "2012-05-31 11:06:50">, 
#<ActivityState id: 7354, activity_id: 2033, state_type: 1, created_at: "2012-05-31 11:06:53">, 
#<ActivityState id: 7355, activity_id: 2033, state_type: 2, created_at: "2012-05-31 11:06:59">]
```

It also has several these `nil` activity_state objects appended mid render because of the `.new`:

```
#<ActivityState id: nil, activity_id: 2033, state_type: nil, created_at: nil>
```

resulting in:

```
[#<ActivityState id: 7353, activity_id: 2033, state_type: 0, created_at: "2012-05-31 11:06:50">, 
#<ActivityState id: 7354, activity_id: 2033, state_type: 1, created_at: "2012-05-31 11:06:53">, 
#<ActivityState id: 7355, activity_id: 2033, state_type: 2, created_at: "2012-05-31 11:06:59">,
#<ActivityState id: nil, activity_id: 2033, state_type: nil, created_at: nil>,
#<ActivityState id: nil, activity_id: 2033, state_type: nil, created_at: nil>]
```

Which then messes things up when I loop over the activity_states for the activity and render them.  I tried a hacky way of getting around this using: `<% activity.activity_states.pop %>` after each form_for but this doesn't work when in production on Heroku as it complains about trying to modify a frozen array.

Any ideas on the "right" way of doing this please?  I know I'm failing to understand something pretty fundamental here and also know I've opened up a hole by inserting a hidden field for the id field ([which can then be manipulated by malicious users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965791/form-for-new-related-model/6966019#comment14109104_6966019)).

Comment: Why do you need to create temporary activity states at all? This would be better done in the model. You are struggling because you are mixing business logic with the view layer. All business logic belongs in the model. this needs further discussion - Look at my profile for a link to the Rails forum and post in there as you can't really have a discussion in stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi @jamesw , thanks very much for your comment.  I haven't acted on this as I haven't returned to this project yet.  When I do I'll definitely post it on the Rails forum.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution so far, in the `show` method of the `activity controller`, include:

```
@new_activity_state = @activity.activity_states.new
@activity.activity_states.pop
```

and in the view partial (which I pass `@activity` as the local variable `activity`):

```
<% new_activity_state = @new_activity_state || activity.activity_states.new %>
<%= form_for new_activity_state, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :state_type, :value => activity_state_type %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :activity_id %>
    <%= f.submit submit_label, :disable_with => 'sending...' %>
<% end %>
```

Heroku's production environment doesn't object to the .pop now which is great :D  But is there a better way?